# Using inner product to prove that a function is an isometry...

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, derivatives, vector-analysis, isometry

$\textbf{My problem:}$ Let $f:\mathbb{R^m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ be a function of class $C^1$ such that for each $x\in \mathbb{R^m}$, $|f'(x)\cdot  v|=|v|$. Prove that $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|$ for each $x, y\in \mathbb{R^m}$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ I take $a,b\in \mathbb{R^m}$ distincts. then I consider the function $\varphi :[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\varphi (t)=\langle f(a(1-t)+bt),b-a\rangle$. I have that $\varphi $ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$. Then for mean value theorem, there exist $x\in (0,1)$ such that $\varphi (1)-\varphi (0)=\varphi '(x)$. Whit this, I can conclude easily:

$\langle f(b)-f(a)-f'(a+x(b-a))\cdot (b-a), b-a\rangle=0$

I want deduce from this that $f(b)-f(a)-f'(a+x(b-a))\cdot (b-a)=0$, because in this case, I'd have  $f(b)-f(a)=f'(a+x(b-a))\cdot (b-a)$, which implies $|f(b)-f(a)|=|f'(a+x(b-a))\cdot (b-a)|=|b-a|.$ However, I don't achieve to prove that $f(b)-f(a)-f'(a+x(b-a))\cdot (b-a)=0$...Is impossible deduce this fact from my develop?...any suggestions?

Comment: With the mean value theorem you will only get $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \le \|x-y\|$. Your problem is harder than it seems. For an answer see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228964/functions-with-orthogonal-jacobian

Comment: @Gerd I didn't achieve view an answer in your link, but I appreciate your effort in helping me.

Comment: The direction $||f(b)-f(a)|| \leq ||b-a||$ is clear, because your path $x\mapsto f(a+x(b-a))$ from $f(a)$ to $f(b)$ has length $||b-a||$.  The other direction seems to involve the topology of $\mathbb{R}^m$, as it is not true of arbitrary maps between ($C^1$) manifolds,  so I would not be surprised if it were much harder, as Gerd says.  (+1) and thanks for highlighting a question which it is easy to overlook.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190234/if-the-derivative-of-frm-to-rm-is-isometric-then-f-is-isometric

Comment: @Moed Pol Bollo definitly there is the proof. Thanks

Comment: Although the universal quantification of $x\in \mathbb R^m$ is stated, it should also be given for $v$